# Is it possible for all Cauchy-sum sequences to converge, but not to the same number?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

First, let me define the Cauchy integral (which is just like the Riemann integral, except that we always pick the left endpoint of each subinterval when evaluating the function):

(Partitions and their norms are defined as usual, just like in the definition of the Riemann integral.)

*Definition*. Given a function $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ ($ a < b$) and a partition $P = \{a = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_N = b\}$ of $[a, b]$, we define the *Cauchy sum for $f$ corresponding to $P$* to be $C(f, P) = \sum_{n = 1}^Nf(x_{n-1})(x_n - x_{n-1})$.

*Definition*. A function $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ ($ a < b$) is *Cauchy-integrable* iff there exists $I\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $P$ is a partition of $[a, b]$ with $|P| < \delta$, then $|C(f, P) - I| < \varepsilon$. We call $I$ the *Cauchy integral* of $f$. (One can prove $I$ is unique, if it exists.)

Here's my question:

*Question*. Let $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying the following: given any sequence of partitions $(P_m)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $[a, b]$ with $|P_m|\to0$ as $m\to\infty$, we have that the sequence $(C(f, P_m))_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges. Can I conclude $f$ is Cauchy-integrable?

Since $f$ is Cauchy-integrable iff all the Cauchy-sum sequences $(C(f, P_m))_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to the same real number, I could restate my question thus:

Is it possible for all Cauchy-sum sequences to converge, but not to the same number?

Comment: Mix two sequences. Will the mixed sequence converge if the original sequences converged to different numbers?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sigh, silly me. Thank you.